# Create different classes, a CarDemo class and a Car class

Tags: java

Creating an external Car class and driver CarDemo class.  Alter the instructions for the CarDemo class to include two methods (getInputYear() that returns a year between 1940 and 2016 and getInputMake() that returns the make of the car and checks for an empty String).

It compiles without errors but It only asks for the  year model input and then prints out everything else on its own.

```
public class Car
{
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    // initialize variables

    Car(int y, String m)
{
        yearModel = y;
        make = m;
        speed = 0;
}

    // setYear method
    public void setYearModel(int y)
{
        yearModel = y;
}
    // setMake method
    public void setMake(String m)
{           make = m;

}

    // set speed method
    public void setSpeed(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }

    // getYearModel method
    public int getYearModel()
    {
        return yearModel;
    }
    // getMake method
    public String getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }
    // getSpeed method
    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }
    // accelerate method accelerates the car's speed by 5

    public void accelerate()
    {
        speed += 5;
    }

    // brake method decreases the car's speed by 5

    public void brake()
    {
        speed -= 5;
    }

}
```

and this is the DemoCar class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarDemo

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
                Car yourCar;
                String make;
                double yearModel, speed;
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.print("What is the car's year model? ");
             yearModel = sc.nextDouble();

             System.out.print("What is the make of the car? ");
             make = sc.nextLine();


            yourCar = new Car(0, make);

            System.out.println("Current status of the car:");
            System.out.println("Year model: " + yourCar.getYearModel());
            System.out.println("Make: " + yourCar.getMake());
            System.out.println("Speed: " + yourCar.getSpeed());

        // Accelerate the car five times.

        System.out.println("Speed up!");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)

        {


            yourCar.accelerate();
            System.out.println("demoCar's speed " + yourCar.getSpeed());// Display the speed.

        }
        System.out.println();
        // Brake the car five times.
        System.out.println("Slow down!");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)

        {

            yourCar.brake();

            System.out.println("demoCar's speed " + yourCar.getSpeed());// Display the speed.

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: add a `sc.nextLine();` after your `yearModel = sc.nextDouble();` Then all should be well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sc.nextDouble();` didn't handle the newline character and your `sc.nextLine()` consumed it and skip the rest.

You can add one more `nextLine()` to capture the left-over newline character.

```
         System.out.print("What is the car's year model? ");
         yearModel = sc.nextDouble();

         boolean isInRange = (1940 <= yearModel） && (yearModle <= 2016);

         if(!isInRange){
             // not in range
             return;
         }

         sc.nextLine(); // consumes the left-over newline character.

         System.out.print("What is the make of the car? ");
         make = sc.nextLine();
```

**Alternatively**:

```
   System.out.print("What is the make of the car? ");
   make = sc.nextLine();
```

change `sc.nextLine()` to `sc.next()`

method `next()` finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

Comment: @mvanderk10  `nextDouble()` doesn't capture the newline character

Comment: Where would I put this part of my program (getInputYear() that returns a year between 1940 and 2016 and getInputMake() that returns the make of the car and checks for an empty String). where would that if statement for between the year 1940-2016 go?

Comment: you can check `yearModel` whether between 1940 and 2016 after line `yearModel = sc.nextDouble();`   You'd better use integer for year other than double

Comment: what if i want a method to do that within the democar class? I would have make a new method and put that method in the if statement? and what if I want to prompt the user to enter a new year if it is outside the years?